# Mud cracks formation

Tags: geology, rocks, structural-geology, stratigraphy

Are mud cracks formed during rock formation or after the rock is completely formed?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mud cracks are created at the surface of mud, as the name implies.
Afterwards, due to burial processes, younger sediments may fill in the cracks.

Later, the mud-cracked-with-infilled-sediments system will lithify, as visible in this nice vertical section of an infilled mud-crack [the photo is made by Michael C. Rygel and is accessible via Wikimedia Commons of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudcrack#/media/File:Mudcracks_mcr3.jpg) .